# Pandas sudden error in code

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
A      B      C      D
a      d      a      z
b      c      z      c
```

My goal is to pull out the column names where df == 'z' so I used:

```
df['ColumnNames'] = df.where(df=='z' ).stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply('+ '.join)
```

It used to work fine; however today I got an error saying:  "TypeError: Could not compare ['z'] with block values"

Does anyone know why this happens? Many thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error you have. Did you make any changes to your python packages in recent days? Have you tried to re-run your code or restart your jupyter notebook? What's your python and pandas version?

Comment: My guess is that you have a version of pandas that is borking when comparing `int` to `str`.  Try `df.astype(object) == 'z'`

Comment: Thank you for all the help.  I pulled the data from SQL maybe something changed in the back end but I was about to fix it now.

Comment: @piRSquared feel free to modify it :-) make it community :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code working fine on my side, check whether contain space in your df , also we short it with

```
df[df=='z'].stack()
Out[216]: 
0  D    z
1  C    z
dtype: object

df[df=='z'].stack().index.get_level_values(1)
Out[218]: Index(['D', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

From the Comment above by PiR

***My guess is that you have a version of pandas that is borking when comparing int to str. Try df.astype(object) == 'z'***

Comment: it wasn't a space or anything.  I think it must be one of the data type problem.  I was about to fix it now with df.astype(str) =='z'.  It's weird because I just got the problem today but before it was fine.

Comment: @TylerNG aha , That is ok , I will make this answer to community and adding Pir 's solution